# wxPython button on each frame of notepad that closes application

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a `wxpython` class Neoprobe which has 3 classes/notebook pages

```
class Neoprobe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Neoprobe QC Application",size=(750,900))


        # Here we create a panel and a notebook on the panel
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(panel)

        # create the page windows as children of the notebook
        page1 = Sensitivity(nb)
        page2 = Angular(nb)
        page3 = Distance(nb)

        # add the pages to the notebook with the label to show on the tab
        nb.AddPage(page1, "Sensitivity")
        nb.AddPage(page2, "Angular")
        nb.AddPage(page3, "Distance")
```

I would like an exit button that closes the application on each page of the notebook. For example in the page 'Angular' I have the following code

```
class Angular(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
    .
    .
    .

        hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        graph_btn = wx.Button(top_panel, label='Plot', size=(70, 30))
        hbox2.Add(graph_btn)
        db_btn = wx.Button(top_panel, label='Update db', size=(100, 30))
        hbox2.Add(db_btn, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.BOTTOM, border=5)
        exit_btn = wx.Button(top_panel, label='Exit', size=(70, 30))
        hbox2.Add(exit_btn, flag=wx.LEFT|wx.BOTTOM, border=5)
        top_panel_sizer.Add(hbox2, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.RIGHT, border=10)

        #Setup button bindings
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit, exit_btn)

        def OnExit(self,event):
            dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self,
               "Do you really want to close this application?",
               "Confirm Exit", wx.OK|wx.CANCEL|wx.ICON_QUESTION)
            result = dlg.ShowModal()
            dlg.Destroy()
            if result == wx.ID_OK:
                self.Close()
```

However, this (obviously) does not close the wx.Frame. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to close the application then you need to call something along the lines of:

```
top = wx.GetApp().GetTopWindow()
top.Close()
```

**Edit:** *Corrected code to use the static wx.GetApp() to retrieve the application.*

Comment: this gives me the error message `if warn: warnings.warn(_use_error_msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./NeoprobeApp2.py", line 304, in OnExit
    top = self.GetTopWindow()
AttributeError: 'Angular' object has no attribute 'GetTopWindow'
`

Comment: The amended answer will use `wx.GetApp()` to get the application - Calling `Close` on the Top Window is the same as clicking the __X__ in the corner of it.